# Return statement from catch block in case of exception occurs from repository layer?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am little confused what response should I send back whenever the repository layer throws exception.

I have a controller which calls an service and then service calls an repository to return data.

```
public class ProductController : Controller
 {

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts()
     {
        return _productService.GetAllProducts();
     }
 }


public class ProductService: IProductService
 {
   public List<Product> GetAllProducts()
    {
     return _productRepository.GetProducts();
    }
 }


public class ProductRepository: IProductRepository
  {
    public List<Product> GetProducts()
        {
            try
            {
                //database call to get products;
                }
            }
             catch(Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error("Exception occurred while calling GetProducts", ex);
                return new List<Product>();
            }
        }
  }
```

If I return new list it is the same response if database returns empty data-set but if any exception occurred I want to return a different response from the controller.

What I am thinking is to return null from repository layer and then in service layer I can check if response is null, then I can return an error message with empty list of products to the controller.

or

should I not handle exceptions in repository layer and just check for exceptions in service layer and then return the message and empty list of products back to controller if any exception occurred.

and then controller can check if there is any error message then return 500 HTTP status code along with message and empty list.

I am confused what is the right way to handle exceptions and returning error message. what is the right approach to return error message with HTTP Status Code?

Comment: As far as I remember, the default is a 500 response if you do not handle any exceptions explicitly. And that's what I'd do if I had no good reason not to. I'd test and make sure a production user won't see stacktraces or anything like that (in general too much information about the internal error).

Comment: Don't catch (swallow) exceptions you can't handle. Log them, but then rethrow them. If you don't want to throw exceptions, create a generic response model that serves as a wrapper for your repository response. But in general, let it fail, but prevent sensitive data from reaching the end user. (This is normally already set up for a template mvc app). Also, this will probably close as primarily opinion based. Maybe put it on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Don't return null. If null is even a possibility then it means something, like there were no results. (An empty list would be way, way better.) If you return null because of an exception, now null can mean two things. It can mean no results or an exception. Even if you somehow end up telling the user the right thing, no one who has to read and debug the code should have to understand things like, "If the result is null, that means there was an exception." An *exception* means that there was an exception.

Comment: I think that is good idea to swallow the exception and then create an generic response model to return the custom error message which will prevent the sensitive internal information from reaching out to end user. Thank you guys.

Comment: Yes, we should make sure that the original exception with internal details doesn't get leaked all the way out. All they need is a 500 response. To split hairs, we don't call that 'swallowing' the exception. That's when we catch it and don't do anything or act like there was no exception.

Comment: @Sahil that would be a *terrible* idea and the client developers will **hate it**. 200 means success. Returning an error code deep inside a model while claiming *success* means the client code will have to read and parse the entire response just to see if there *is* any data to parse and process.

Comment: I'd rather propagate the exception up to the highest point and handle it there to properly structure a response. The Repository should only care about giving a result always in the same form (a List), whether none (an empty list), one or multiple.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is that log that error you got in Repository and then from Web API try managing status code so that client also handle error in frontend.